# Attempting to return multiple maps in jsx (react)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I currently am looping through an array and then trying to loop through an object

```
  return optionsGroup.map(optionItem => {
    return (
      <span className="select-wrapper-size {{selectExtraclassNameDetail}}" data-ng-show="variation_exist">
          <select className="form-control size-select" name="size" required>
              <option value="" selected>Select {optionItem}</option>

              { Object.keys(shopProduct['options'].map(optEl => {
                return (<option data-ng-repeat="var in variations" value="{{var}}">{optEl[optionItem]}</option>)
              }))
              }

          </select>
      </span>
    )
```

The above as is displays on html side but is missing this area:

```
      { Object.keys(shopProduct['options'].map(optEl => {
        return (<option data-ng-repeat="var in variations" value="{{var}}">{optEl[optionItem]}</option>)
      }))
      }
```

This isn't being returned so then I attempt this:

```
      { return Object.keys(shopProduct['options'].map(optEl => {
        return (<option data-ng-repeat="var in variations" value="{{var}}">{optEl[optionItem]}</option>)
      }))
      }
```

This gives me a syntax error.  My question is how can I return that nested Object.keys map?

Comment: Looks like you had a typo. Could you also share your shopProducts variable. Object.keys is going to return an array of keys so I doubt you're able to execute this statement `optEl[optionItem]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a parens before the .map method

```
 { Object.keys(shopProduct['options']).map(optEl => {
        return (<option data-ng-repeat="var in variations" value="{{var}}">{optEl[optionItem]}</option>)
      }))
      }
```

Comment: Ah! Great catch! Thank you!